# Geneva Framework licensing cost

Tags: licensing, geneva-framework

Is the framework once released as per microsoft later in the year 2009, going to br free or any licensing cost associated with its usage? Any insider information at this stage would greatly be appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing cost instead of directly about programming or software development. See the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *guess*, is that your Windows license will allow you to use it for free.

Comment: would you need Vista OS for development?

Comment: You can do dev on any box that runs Vista, Windows Server 2003 or better.  There's been a little talk about possibly supporting XP too by RTM, but I have no inside news on that front.

Answer (score 1):

Stuard Kwan, the group program manager for the Federated Identity Team answered this on the Geneva Forums here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/2dbad293-e82d-47ab-b3f2-f474cdb753b8

"All of the "Geneva" components (Server, Framework, and Windows CardSpace "Geneva") will be Windows components and available to Windows licensees at no additional charge."

Best regards,

SV.